# play a movie in cocoa application

Tags: cocoa, qtkit

i want to know how to play a movie in Cocoa application

Comment: It's "Cocoa" not "COCOA"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a [QTMovieView](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/QuickTime/Reference/QTKitFramework/Classes/QTMovieView_Class/) in one of your application's windows. Set the movie view's movie to an instance of QTMovie; see the description of `setMovie:` on that page for details.